# scala test fails though actual appears to match expected

Tags: scala, unit-testing

I am taking the Coursera course Functional Programming in Scala. If you have qualms about providing the solutions to problems, this does not pertain directly to the assignment.

I am finding myself frequently unclear about what is happening. So, I use tests to gain insight. In the assignment for the current week a set of tests are included. In the suite of tests a couple functions are defined - size and asSet, the latter of which converts a TweetSet to Set[Tweet]. I created tests for both. The size tests work just fine. The asSet works for the empty set, but it fails with a set of one element. The output message sure makes it seem like what I have done is correct, so I have no idea at present what is wrong.

The result message is:

```
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: Set(User: a
Text: a body [20]) did not equal Set(User: a
Text: a body [20])
```

As you can see, it states that the result is equal to the expect. Here is the failing test:

```
  test("asSet: on singleton set") {
    new TestSets {
        assert(asSet(set2) === Set[Tweet](new Tweet("a", "a body", 20)))
    }
  }
```

The function is defined as follows (this was provided in the course materials):

```
  def asSet(tweets: TweetSet): Set[Tweet] = {
    var res = Set[Tweet]()
    tweets.foreach(res += _)
    res
  }
```

The definition of set2 as follows (again, provided):

```
val set1 = new Empty
val set2 = set1.incl(new Tweet("a", "a body", 20))
```

Tweet is defined as follows:

```
class Tweet(val user: String, val text: String, val retweets: Int) {
  override def toString: String =
    "User: " + user + "\n" +
    "Text: " + text + " [" + retweets + "]"
}
```

What am I missing such that this test is failing though looks like it should be passing?

Comment: Check if tweet is a case class. If not they can be different , even if they contain the same data, as the equals and toHascode is implemented in a different way.

Comment: I'v added the definition of Tweet. I had to look up the definition of case class. As I understand it, you have a super class (abstract?) and multiple classes that extend the super class using the case keyword. Tweet does not extend anything, nor does it use the case keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Your test fails because of the way **hashCode** is implemented.

- To compare with **==** Scala uses the **equals** method which is implemented on every class.
- To determine if a instance is contained in a Set or to use it as key Scala uses the **hashCode** method

**The basic source of your error**
As you have implemented *Tweet* every instance is different, even if it contains the same information.

```
scala> val x= Set(new Tweet( "me", "test message", 1),new Tweet( "me", "test message", 1) )
  x: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Tweet] =
  Set(User: me
      Text: test message [1 ],
      User: me
      Text: test message [1 ])

 scala> x.size
 res3: Int = 2
```

How this methods are implemented differs with classes and case classes.

**Example**

**with normal class**

```
class Tweet(val user: String, val text: String, val retweets: Int) {
  override def toString: String = 
    s"""User: $user
    |Text: $text [$retweets ]""".stripMargin
}



scala> val x = new Tweet( "me", "test message", 1)
x: Tweet =
  User: me
  Text: test message [1 ]

scala> x == x
res0: Boolean = true

scala> x == new Tweet( "me", "test message", 1)
res1: Boolean = false
```

**with case class**

```
case class Tweet(val user: String, val text: String, val retweets: Int) {
   override def toString: String = 
   s"""User: $user
       |Text: $text [$retweets ]""".stripMargin
}

scala> val x = new Tweet( "me", "test message", 1)
x: Tweet =
  User: me 
  Text: test message [1 ]

scala> x == x
res2: Boolean = true

scala> x == new Tweet( "me", "test message", 1)
res3: Boolean = true

scala> (new Tweet( "me", "test message", 1)).hashCode
res6: Int = -1967705983

scala> (new Tweet( "me", "test message", 1)).hashCode
res7: Int = -1967705983
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that in the assignment you are manually developing an implementation of `Set`, whereas on the other hand you used Scala's internal `Set` type to compare it to; i.e. you are comparing two instances of different types.

I believe the right-hand side of this line creates a `scala.collection.immutable.Set`

```
assert(asSet(set2) === Set[Tweet](new Tweet("a", "a body", 20)))
```